# Different build results in multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven, classpath, multi-module

I have a multi project maven structure, with a parent pom.
Parent pom just references the modules to build. Those modules have their sub-modules etc (it's a quite big and complicated structure). All projects are maven 2 projects, and conform to maven standards. So I have something like this

parent pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>framework</module> 
    <module>server</module> 
    <module>utils</module> 
</modules>
```

framework pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>gui</module> 
    <module>ear</module> 
    <module>libs</module> 
</modules>
```

If I run mvn clean install from ear submodule where I have my ear, it is build as expected.
When I run my mvn clean install from framework, I have the same result.
But when I run it from top level, my ear contains additional libraries that I dont want to have (I excluded them in my ear pom.xml). 
Any ideas?

Edit:
I exclude the unwanted libs in my ear pom in a classic way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ear.dependency</groupId>
    <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>unwanted.lib</groupId>
             <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I also compared the mvn dependency:tree from top level pom and framework pom, and regarding the ear section, they're the same

Comment: Could you provide how you did exclude those libraries?

Comment: Do you have any dependencies in your parent pom? Maybe the submodules inherit something?

Comment: In my parent pom I have a dependencyManagement section which lists all my projects and their versions, but no dependencies section

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `mvn help:effective-pom -pl :ear` from the root and from the `framework` folder. Compare the two outputs.

Comment: If I run exactly what you passed it says there is no :ear path... If I do mvn -pl ear help:effective-pom in framework it prints me the framework effective pom, and when I do similar in parent, it prints effective parent pom... Not sure if this is what you wanted (I'm using maven 2.2.1)

Comment: You need to replace `:ear` with the name of the EAR artifact. `-pl :artifactId` means "create the reactor and then run just this single module."

Comment: Still, this does not work, even if I pass path to my ear module, it prints effective pom of the directory where I execute the command and not efective pom of the ear

Comment: Works for me but I'm using Maven 3.2.1. Consider upgrading; that may already solve your issue.